# how to use 'sudo' without using 'become' modules

Tags: ansible

Thanks for reading.

Is there a way to use the `sudo command` without using the `become module` while writing ansible playbook? (This is the case when the `shell module` is also not used.)

Currently, in my environment, the sudo command can be executed, but it is not possible to switch to root with commands such as sudo -i or sudo su -.

So settings like become: yes don't work.

I want to use it like below.

ex) testuser can use the sudo command, but cannot access as root with commands such as sudo -i.

```
- name: install default packages
  become: yes
  shell: "yum install -y smem"
  remote_user: testuser
```

-> This doesn't work, but you can use the sudo command from testuser,
-> sudo yum install -y smem

ex2)

```
- name: sett nproc
  become: yes
  pam_limits:
    domain: user1
    limit_type: '-'
    limit_item: nproc
    value: 257521
  remote_user: testuser
```

As a way to solve the problem, I can only think of a way to manually enter the sudo command using the shell module or, in the case of ex2's limits.conf, to modify it by putting markers in the blockcinfile.

Any good way?

thank you

have a good day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to run ansible without root permissions is going to be really fiddly. It looks like you have sudo access to a set of restricted commands and that is all.

The only sensible way I can think of doing this would be to copy over a set of utility scripts to `/home/testuser/bin/` and call those as testuser. So you would have something like `/home/testuser/bin/sudo_yum.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo yum install -y "$@"
```

That's horrible, fiddly to get the quoting safe on the parameters and renders most of the ansible modules un-usable.

If you really can't grant ansible the access it needs, maybe you need a different configuration tool. It looks like you can install packages, so something with an agent running as root might be permitted.